# had no method 'push' mongoDB nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to push an element into an array (Nodejs / mongoDB) with an update method.

I have an error message " xxxx@xxxx.com has no method 'push'".

```
if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Photo.findOne({name: name}, function (err, photo) {
    console.log(photo);
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!photo) { return res.send(404); }
      photo.email.push(email);
      photo.save(function (err) {
                  if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      });
```

photo.email.push(email);
                  ^
TypeError: Object xxxx@xxxx.com has no method 'push'

Thanks for your answers

Comment: `photo.email` is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: Yes, I juste want to update a collection something like that : {email : "xxx@xxx.com", "yyy@yyy.com"};

Comment: That's not how arrays look like in JavaScript... You maybe want `{email: ["xxx@xxx.com", "yyy@yyy.com"]}`.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the mistake, I want {email: ["xxx@xxx.com", "yyy@yyy.com"]}

Comment: I juste change a lign on my model, I modify the field of email like this email: [string] before it was like that email: string, now it's work, thanks Madara Uchiha